# Can point-system be used for hypothesis testing?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing

I've created a point system for the bestseller's list (I've 52 weeks' lists).The list has 4 categories of genre (romance, thriller, fantasy, literary fiction).

```
Rank  Points  Week 1   Week 2   Week 3              

 1     10     Thriller Thriller Thriller        
 2     9      Romance  Fantasy  Fantasy         
 3     8      Fantasy  Romance  Romance         
 4     7      Romance  Romance  Romance         
 5     6      Thriller Fantasy  Fantasy         
 6     5      Romance  Romance  Lit Fic.
 7     4      Romance  Romance  Romance 
 8     3      Thriller Thriller Thriller
 9     2      Fantasy  Lit Fic. Romance 
10     1      Romance  Thriller Romance
```

Below are the result after adding up the points. The points represent the performance (in points) of each genre on weekly basis. (For example: Thriller in week 1 comes at Rank- 1,5 & 8. So, the performance points for the same will be the points corresponding to the ranks i.e (10+6+3)= **19**

```
  Week Thriller Romance Fantasy General Fiction

    1       19      26      10           0
    2       14      24      15           2
    3       13      22      15           5
```

Can I use these score points for hypothesis testing? Or how else can I use this data to make a comparison between different genres?

Comment: Could you formulate a clear hypothesis for our consideration?  Exactly what kind of comparison are you hoping to make?  How do you intend to interpret the results?

Comment: I was thinking of using one of these non-parametric test: I'm not sure whether Mann Whitney u test should be used taking two genres at a time to check if there's any difference between two genres or Kruskal Wallis test for k independent samples. @whuber

Comment: That's a statistical procedure, but it's not a hypothesis.  It's not apparent what one might be able to learn about these genres from these data, so it's important to tell us what your aim is.

Comment: My initial aim was to check the effect on other subsequent weeks' list due to an occurrence of a genre in a particular week. But I was told that it is not possible with this data. Because this is the only limited data that is available to me related to my topic, therefore I need to work with this only. Since I have 52 weeks of data, my aim is to check if  w.r.t time, any two or more samples provide same performance scores or not. I'm not quite sure how I'll achieve it. Any help will be appreciable. @whuber

Comment: Not clear to me why or even how  points are being assigned. Maybe  explain how if you have not yet decided why. What does the data look like before assigning points? Why week 1,2,3?  You  initially say 52 weeks. What are you  doing, please?

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd question your method of creating points. Why should ranks be additive? The difference in sales between rank 1 and rank 2 may be very different from that between rank 9 and 10. And the difference between 1 and 2 in week 1 may be very different from the difference in week 2. So, that's going to make the data very messy.

Next, if you are willing to accept that mess, you have to figure out what you want to figure out. Can you do a hypothesis test? Sure. Which one? That depends on what you  are trying to find out. Apparently you want to compare the ranks across the groups. Then one starting place is ANOVA/linear regression - but the assumptions are likely to be violated (so should be checked).

If those assumptions are not met, then I suggest some form of regression that does not make the assumptions. Quantile regression might work well.